# How to make this code not loop through all the worksheets?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub SalesPersonTotal()
    Dim employee As String, total As Long, Sheet As Worksheet, i As Long

    total = 0
    employee = InputBox("Enter the employee name (case sensitive)")

    For Each Sheet In Worksheets

        For i = 6 To 35

            If Sheet.Cells(i, 5).Value = employee Then
                total = total + Sheet.Cells(i, 10).Value
            End If

        Next i
    Next Sheet

    MsgBox "Total sales of " & employee & " is " & total

End Sub
```

Comment: If you don't want to loop over all sheets, don't use `For Each Sheet In Worksheets` What is it you want to do?

Comment: I removed the For Each Sheet In Worksheets, and received an error "Object variable or With block variable not set". What should I change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid Looping through all sheets
Remove

```
For Each Sheet in Worksheets
```

Explicitly mention sheet name

```
Sheets("YourSheetName").Cells(i, 5).Value
```

In place of this type of codes

```
Sheet.Cells(i, 5).Value
```

Comment: I get this "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: Have you modified this code as well? `total + Sheet.Cells(i, 10).Value`

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I modified that line as well and got it!